# createStore throws unknown error due to connectRouter and persistReducer being present

Tags: typescript, redux, router, redux-persist

I have a working store and I am at the point where I need to implement redux state persistence.

However, following the tutorials I ended up and the point below and the persistedReducer inside the createStore function throws this error:

> TS2560: Value of type 'Reducer<{ auth: Readonly<{ access_token: string | null; Authorization: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; isLoggingIn: boolean; user: { permissions: { approvals: boolean; breaches: boolean; }; role: "admin" | null; }; }>; dialog: Readonly<...>; notifications: State; user: State; } & PersistPartial, AnyAction>' has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial<{ auth: Readonly<{ access_token: string | null; Authorization: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; isLoggingIn: boolean; user: { permissions: { approvals: boolean; breaches: boolean; }; role: "admin" | null; }; }>; dialog: Readonly<...>; notifications: State; user: State; }>'. Did you mean to call it?

I think it's trying to communicate. Can someone tell me why this is happening because I don't understand that statement at all.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  persistedReducer,   <----error occurs here
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
      routerMiddleware(history)
    )
  )
)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```